# Why is only one side of the object affected by subdivision surface?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

Why is only one side of the object affected by subdivision surface?

[image: please help me]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add an image of your object in edit mode.

Comment: Maybe you have activated the Auto-Smooth option in the Properties > Data > Normals menu, it will create a sharp edge on each edge that have an angle above the amount you have defined

Comment: Could you have possibly put an edge crease around that edge loop? It would show up as a different colour to other edges in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think the subdivision has applied equally to the whole surface (check the wireframe).. but maybe some of it is flat-shaded, and some of it is not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either you have high crease value or you somehow put a loop cut there but you can't see it bc it's overlapping.

First try to merge by distance with like 0.001, select all verts and make the crease value zero.

[image: merge and crease]

In addition you also can enable auto merge and split edges then press G and ENTER without actually moving the mesh.

[image: split edges]